# Hide Specific Div on the user event (i.e click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I open the my notifications are by clicking on bell image on top of page it just alight and open correctly
but now i want whenever user click inside the div of notification then notification box appear same as it but whenever clicks outside div it closes (div id is HSnotifications)

Comment: What's the question? :D

Comment: Is it a popup `data-role=popup`? Pls post the markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the document listen to the click event.

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $(e.target);

    // You are checking the current clicked element is the div 
    // or any of the descendants of the notifications div
    if ($target.closest('#HSnotifications').length) {
        // Clicked inside the notifications.

        // do something
    } else if ($target.is('#showNotificationsBtn')) {
       // If bell button is clicked open the notification
        $('#HSnotifications').show();

    } else {

        // close notifications

        $('#HSnotifications').hide()
    }

});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/NzXMB/)**

Comment: As a sidenote, `closest()` starts with the current element, so there is no need for `$target.is(....)`, as `closest()` does the same thing. Still +1, this is the way to do it.

Comment: Did you try `$('#HSnotifications').close()` on console in OP's site? I got "has no method 'close' ", so I used `.hide()`.

Comment: @Sergio .. I did not try that.. Looks like a a ui-panel . Not sure of the method that is used to close it

Comment: @Sushanth--Now when i click on bell icon the notification div not appear the bell icon is in anchor tag and id is showNotificationsBtn

Comment: @Sushanth--In start when notification div is not appear and i click on bell sign to appear notification div then this check '$target.closest('#HSnotifications').length' return 0 and else executes in which this is '$('#HSnotifications').hide()' present

Comment: @BluAngel.. Try this selector then `$(document).not('#showNotificationsBtn')`

Comment: @Sushanth--like this $(document).not('#showNotificationsBtn').on('click', function(e) ??

Comment: @Sushanth--tried but now it doesn't enter in this function body  $(document).not('#showNotificationsBtn').on('click', function(e)

Comment: @BluAngel .. check updated post.. Just move the click event inside the document handler or just have an extra condition

Comment: @Sushanth--   now it opens on double click not on single click

Comment: When i click on bell icon control directly goes into else theoretically it would goes to else if the id  #showNotificationsBtn is an id for anchor tag

Comment: Right that is what the 2nd condition does

Comment: what should i do now  @Sushanth--

Comment: ahh I see.. Replace the else if condition with `$target.closest('#showNotificationsBtn').length`  Looks like it has nested elements as well

Comment: @Sushanth-- Now i uploaded it here http://engineers-web.com/F09/api/test/test/newsfeed.html

Comment: I would like to help, but have to go sleep. I think there is a preventDefault on click in one of many .js files. That's maybe why it works to open on doubleclick and not single. The close seems to work good now, congrats :) Good luck @BluAngel & Sushanth.

Comment: @BluAngel .. Replace `else if ($target.is('#showNotificationsBtn')) {` with `else if ($target.closest('#showNotificationsBtn').length) {`.  Then you have 2 places where you have defined the click event .. One is in `script.js`  remove that handler as you are already doing so in the script tag  `$('#hideNotificationsBtn').on('click',function(){ $('#HSnotifications').hide(); })` can be removed

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need. When clicking the background overlay, hide/close the `HSnotifications`.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ui-panel-content-wrap').click(function (event) {
        if ($(event.target).hasClass('ui-panel-content-wrap')){
            $('#HSnotifications').hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Jonast92, I am often the slow guy :))

Comment: @Sergio-- I tried your answer but it can not disappears the notification div

Comment: @BluAngel, I ran the code on the console at you site and worked. Click the window = all ok, click the background = close the window.

Comment: i will try again maybe i miss something

Comment: @BluAngel, i updated my answer with a doomready tag. The code in my answer can be posted anywere inside your page.

Comment: @BluAngel, when is the code to the window loaded? the code I posted has to be loaded after the html for the window. I cannot see the function that is triggered by the bell button.

Comment: @BluAngel Are you doing the changes live on the link you gave?

Comment: @BluAngel, can you put my answer code on the link you provided? http://engineers-web.com/F09/api/test/newsfeed.html, then I can also see if there is a problem.